# How to customize input type="file" or primeng p-fileUpload to desired design?

Tags: angular, file-upload, frontend

I would like to customize design for input type="file" or primeng p-fileUpload. Can someone give a hint how to do it?

Actual result:

[image]

[image]

Expected result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I didn't work with exact this type of input in primeng but worked with that library a lot. So here are steps to override styles for its components:

1. pass styles or style classes to the componen if it accept ones or use inline styles.
2. global classes with higher precision (scope to your angular component if it necessary only there)
3. global styles with `!important`
4. `::ng-deep`.
   Last one is better not to use at all. The 3rd one should be used only for styles which are already provided as inline by the 3rd party library.